# MySQL get list based on expiry date... from 3 columns date

Tags: mysql, date

My code is :

```
SELECT    container_id, site_id,  date(CERTVALIDITY), date(TESTVALIDITY), date(VALVE_VALIDITY), DATEDIFF(date(CERTVALIDITY),now()) AS daysleft
FROM        tbl_cont
WHERE       date(CERTVALIDITY)  BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 month) 
ORDER BY    date(CERTVALIDITY);
```

shown result edited with original data :

```
+--------------+---------+-------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| cont_id      | site_id | date(EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY) | date(HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY) | date(SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY) | dayscount |
+--------------+---------+-------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
| CT00055      | ST51    | 2020-02-27                    | 2021-03-25               | 2019-03-09                      |         3 |
| CT00078      | ST71    | 2021-03-25                    | 2020-02-28               | 2019-09-22                      |         4 |
| CT00098      | ST94    | 2019-09-22                    | 2021-03-25               | 2020-02-29                      |         5 |
| CT00075      | ST70    | 2020-03-01                    | 2023-09-10               | 2020-07-28                      |         6 |
| CT00056      | ST52    | 2020-03-03                    | 2021-03-25               | 2019-03-09                      |         8 |
+--------------+---------+-------------------------------+--------------------------+---------------------------------+-----------+
```

i want the result to be like this(3 different column dates ) :

```
+--------------+---------+------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| container_id | site_id | date(CERTVALIDITY)     | date(TESTVALIDITY) | date(VALVE_VALIDITY) | daysleft  |
+--------------+---------+------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------+
| CT00055      | ST51    | 2020-02-27             | -                  | -                    |         3 |
| CT00078      | ST71    | -                      | 2020-02-28         | -                    |         4 |
| CT00098      | ST94    | -                      | -                  | 2020-02-29           |         5 |
| CT00075      | ST70    | 2020-03-01             | -                  | -                    |         6 |
| CT00056      | ST52    | 2020-03-03             | -                  | -                    |         8 |
+--------------+---------+------------------------+--------------------+----------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: What's the logic behind copying `CERTVALIDITY` into `TESTVALIDITY` or `VALVE_VALIDITY`?

Comment: one product have 3 type of validity dates... need to check all three dates whichever is going to expire... not copying into other dates... just need to show which date is going to expire

Comment: It would be much easier to answer this if you gave the original data from `tbl_cont` rather than the output of your existing query.

Comment: Dear Nick, [Show Results] is original data of tbl_cont

Comment: In your expected result date(CERTVALIDITY)  for row 2 and 3 is also going to expire as it is equals to the one you displayed, why don't display this date ?

Comment: Dear Gosfly, sry i just copied from show result... but if one column date is going to expire other two shld  be empty...

Comment: *if one column date is going to expire other two shld be empty...* What if 2 or 3 dates "are going to expire"? and what if none date? And how do you define that some date "is going to expire"?

Comment: What is your version of mysql ?

Comment: Dear Akina, the list show all the expire dates of 3 columns thats the idea. no issue if it shows empty or data... but the date shld be expire only...

Comment: MySQL v. 5.7.24 Community Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what you are looking for (i guess) :

```
SELECT
  t1.cont_id,
  t1.site_id,
  CASE WHEN EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY = leastDate THEN EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY END AS EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY,
  CASE WHEN HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY = leastDate THEN HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY END AS HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY,
  CASE WHEN SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY = leastDate THEN SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY END AS SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY,
  DATEDIFF(CASE WHEN leastDate <> '9999-12-31' THEN leastDate END, NOW()) AS daysleft  
FROM tb1_cont t1
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    cont_id,
    LEAST(
      CASE WHEN DATE(EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY) > NOW() THEN DATE(EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY) ELSE '9999-12-31' END,
      CASE WHEN DATE(HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY) > NOW() THEN DATE(HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY) ELSE '9999-12-31' END,
      CASE WHEN DATE(SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY) > NOW() THEN DATE(SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY) ELSE '9999-12-31' END) AS leastDate
  FROM tb1_cont) AS t2
ON t1.cont_id = t2.cont_id
```

[**SEE DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=bb2496be93078e5a36f5af85a644e7a8)

NOTE : If all 3 dates are in the past (already expired) null will be displayed everywhere, as in my demo above.

**EDIT :** If you need to filter on some dates like next week or next month you could add this where clause at the very end of the query :

```
WHERE
  DATE(EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY) BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 month) OR
  DATE(HYDRO_TESTVALIDITY) BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 month) OR
  DATE(SAFETY_VALVE_TESTVALIDITY) BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 month)
```

OR

```
WHERE leastDate BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 month)
```

OR don't use a where clause but just surround the query as below :

```
SELECT * FROM (...) t WHERE t.daysleft < 31
```

Comment: edited : used case when everywhere to be homogeneous

Comment: real useful.. in this query can we have list of date's which is going to expire in 1 week or 1 month alone...??? like follows : date(EXPLOSIVES_CERTVALIDITY)  BETWEEN NOW() AND (NOW() + INTERVAL 1 month)

Comment: Dear gostfly, tried your edited code it works fine... but when i have 3 dates from same row getting expire then it shows only the least date... i want the all 3 expiring dates from same row... [('CT00055','ST51','2020-02-28','2020-02-29','2020-02-29'),]

Comment: What about daysLeft column in this case ?